# How to tell when a Microsoft map object has finished loading

Tags: bing-maps

We're using the Bing Maps AJAX API (v7) to work with maps on our site. The map part itself works, but there are times when the connection to the service is slow. I have some code that needs to run only when the map has completely finished loading. Is there any event or param available in the maps API (I have looked, but can't find anything easily) that will tell me when a map object has completely finished loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "when the map has completely finished loading"?

If you don't have any other elements on the map, then use the `tiledownloadcomplete` event.

If you need to restore the map back to a certain state(with a zoom, location etc), use the `viewchangeend` event.

I don't think there is an event you can use which signifies that the map has completely loaded in the traditional sense.  You can probably approximate this behavior by always causing the map's view to change upon initializing, but eventually arrive at your desired state, so you can subscribe to `viewchangeend` and execute your code in there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at tiledownloadcomplete. What I mean by "completely finished loading": when connection to the bing service is slow, the base layer of the map loads, but it can sometimes take 5 or more seconds for all of the properties (copyright, zoom controls, etc.) to load. I need to know when all of the pieces have loaded.

Comment: If you are willing to get a little hacky, you can have setTimeout loop that checks for the existence of the slow loading elements in the DOM.    Once they are all there, you can be fairly sure everything is pretty much loaded.  I would exhaust other workarounds before doing this though.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found that using the `viewchangeend` method with a callback works.